# Flutter connect real device

Tags: flutter

I am running Windows 10 home edition and every time I launch an AVD the machine slows down considerably.

Is it possible for flutter to connect to a real device such that when I run my app during development its rendered on an actual device and not the virtual devices. If so would hot reloading still be allowed?

Comment: Yes it is possible(It have to be no). Hot reload is also working. Ensure that your adb process running in Task Manager. Run `flutter devices` in terminal for to check plugged in real devices. As guided by below answer.

Comment: Running adb devices command shows no devices attached. Flutter devices also says no devices detected

Comment: Got it. I had enabled developer options but not USB debugging. Thanks for the pointers

Comment: It worked for me after enabling USB debugging with developer options enabled as well

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To prepare to run and test your Flutter app on an Android device, you’ll need an Android device running Android 4.1 (API level 16) or higher.

1. Enable Developer options and USB debugging on your device.
2. Install the Google USB Driver
3. Using a USB cable, plug your phone into your
   computer. If prompted on your device, authorize your computer to
   access your device.
4. In the terminal, run the flutter devices command
   to verify that Flutter recognizes your connected Android device.

You get full instructions and more information here: [Flutter Docs](https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/windows)

Comment: Thank you, Checking. Had missed this in the docs. Will give feedback

Comment: Up and running. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

It's easier to use an emulator and then check the rest with flutter doctor -v

Comment: I suggest you elaborate on your answer.